# How do I capture KeyEventArgs corresponding to localised "%" key?

Tags: wpf

I have a vendor wpf control which is blocking me from receiving TextInput and PreviewTextInput events, however it does let me have the KeyDown event.

How can I map the KeyEventArgs to a localised key mapping (in this case the percent key which on my keyboard is shift-5, but I don't think I can/should rely on that)?